# Use regexp in mysql with where clause in Rails

Tags: mysql, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to use regexp to find some results through where clause. But results are coming as expected. Any help will be really appreciated.

username is `asha123`

Database query

```
User.where('username  REGEXP ?', /(asha|asha)/)
```

Result

```
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (username  REGEXP '--- !ruby/regexp /(asha|asha)/\n...\n')

=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Comment: `(asha|asha)` matches the same rows as simply `asha`.

Answer (score 3):

#### Pass in a string rather than a ruby regular expression.

```
User.where('username  REGEXP ?', '(asha|asha)')
```

Although your database is expecting a "regular expression", `ActiveRecord` isn't - it just wants to replace your `?` with a string value.

Update: to use a variable: just use regular variable interpolation within double quotes. Let's say you had `first_name` and `last_name` variables:

```
User.where('username  REGEXP ?', "(#{first_name}|#{last_name})")
```

Comment: Hey thanks Joshua it works :) How can I give variable in same thing like if I have asha in some variable ? How can I pass it then ?

Comment: No problem. Consider marking the answer as correct.